# Magento 2.0.15 js strings not translated (Adding... and Added)

Tags: magento2, js-translation

On a product-detail page when you click on "Add to cart" it is not correctly translated. In english it says: "Adding..." and "Added". I found that the string is correctly translated in the correct language in "js-translation.json". But on front-end it is not showing the translation ..?

I have removed all var/ and all pub/static folders and then ran:
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL

After clearing cache, nothing has been changed ...? Any solutions?

Comment: Anyone that could help? :-)

Comment: can you share your vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js  or your's catalog-add-to-cart.js if you rewrite it